# Access device between two routers connected to a gateway

Tags: networking, router

I have two routers connected to a modem

Router A (Linksys mx8500):

- connected to the modem and has a gateway IP of 192.168.1.1
- has only one device which is a server with a local IP of 192.168.1.80

Router B (eero S010011):

- connected to the modem and has a gateway IP of 192.168.4.1
- has a lot of devices like my phone and desktop

When attempting to reach my server while not connected to Router B, I am able to connect to it. However, when connecting to the server within Router B it does not work. Connecting to the server within router A does work though. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Does router B know where the 192.168.1 network is? Does it have a *route* towards that network? (And does router A have a route back to your network?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why have you separated the two sub-networks if you wish them to interconnect?

Comment: user1686: I'm unsure, how can I check that it knows that?

Comment: *check that it knows that* - if you haven't specifically added the routes, it's unlikely that they exist, or, that either router even "knows" the other router exists

Comment: Will I have to do Static Routing on both routers? If only one will I enable it on router A or B?

Answer (score 0):

Whether this will be possible on your network depends on how it's set up.

As each router has it's own gateway IP, they each form their own network - and as you've described, devices on each network by default can only connect with other devices on the same network.

This is because, when you send a request to a device not on the same network, the router doesn't know where it should go.

*Routes* are the way that you can tell the router where to send those requests. There are multiple ways routers can get routes, but the main home-use one is *static routes* - where you manually enter them into the router's configuration.

Assuming your modem is a modem-router, and has it's own network, the two routers will each get an IP on the modem's network (i.e. if the modem's network is 192.168.0.X, Router A might get 192.168.0.2 and B might get 192.168.0.3). Thanks to @Tom Yan for this clarification.

In this scenario, on your modem-router, you'd need to configure a route setting all requests bound for 192.168.1.X goes to 192.168.0.2 and all requests bound for 192.168.4.X goes to 192.168.0.3).

Thanks to @Tom Yan for clarifying how this network topology actually most likely looks. Leaving my below incorrect answer for transparency.

<strike>For example, when you connect your two routers together, they should get an IP on each other's network - i.e. Router A gets 192.168.4.2 and Router B gets 192.168.1.2. Then, you can tell Router A "for requests headed to 192.168.4.X, send it to 192.168.1.2" (Router B's address on the network). In the same way, you tell Router B "for requests headed to 192.168.1.X, send it to 192.168.4.2" (Router A's address on the network).</strike>

Unfortunately, judging by [this post](https://community.eero.com/t/80rqzd/static-routes) on eero's community forum, your Router B doesn't have the ability to set these routes - so you can't tell it where to send traffic destined for Router A.

I also can't tell if Router A supports static routes - but I can't see any mention of it in the [user manual](https://downloads.linksys.com/support/assets/userguide/MX8500_USERGUIDE_EN.pdf).

The only fix for this would be to either:

1. Replace both routers with ones that support static routes.
2. Set one router into access point only mode, so that it doesn't provide routing, just additional access points.

Comment: Or "DMZ" the server on router A and access it with router A's WAN IP, assuming the modem is actually a "modem+router" (although in that case security of the server would more or less depend on that of the modem). Port forward selectively might be a better idea too.

Comment: `Set one router into access point only mode` that one router must be the one used for the server though; only by eliminating that extra "LAN" you can access it without extra explicit route.

Comment: Btw the gateway addresses of the required routes (or addresses on the network, in your word, assuming you are referring to the routers' shared WAN) would not be 192.168.1.X or 192.168.4.X, but IP in a different subnet used by the WAN (i.e., the modem's LAN). (`Gateway IP` in the OP appears to be the LAN IP of each router.)

Comment: Also static routes might not be the only setting that is required. Even if the routers uses stateful NAT, they could have firewall rules that filters connection initiated from the WAN side to a LAN client.

Comment: @TomYan my answer was written with the assumption that the modem is just providing an outbound connection for both routers, rather than acting as its own router. But you're right, it makes more sense in this scenario for the modem to be a modem-router. I'll edit the answer to include both scenarios until the OP has more details.

Comment: Actually looking at it further, my original answer didn't quite make sense. Updated with your mentioned topology.